# DIV centered when other div removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div's next to each other - left one and right one.

There is possibility, that the right one will be gone, then i want the left one to be centered.

HTML

```
<div class="contener">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
  width: 75%;
  height: 240px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: "There is possibility, that the right one will be gone" - in what case?

Comment: the right one will be removed by JS ?

Comment: define *gone* and explain how.

Comment: It will be removed by JS, not hidden by CSS

Comment: when you remove the right div, change the left div so that it is `margin:auto` instead of `float:left`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.contender{
 text-align:center;
}
.left {
  width: 75%;
  height: 240px;
  text-align:left;
  display:inline-block;
  zoom:1;
   *display:inline;
 }
.right {
  width: 25%;
  height: 250px;
  text-align:left;
  display:inline-block;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline;
 }
```

the asterisk(`*`) is used to fix `ie7` so it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: If you use this you will need to comment the white space out between the divs otherwise the right div will be pushed down a line and you'll probably want to add `text-align:left` to the inner divs otherwise their content will be centred as well

Comment: awesome catch @pete I've added the `text-align:left;`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, i just need to add vertical-align to the left element. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `display` property of `.left` and `.right` to `inline-block` and set the `text-align:center` for the parent element as [jayaguilar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472418/jayaguilar) pointed out. However, not that this won't work with the exact `html` and css you've.

You need to either remove the `line break` between inline elements in your `html` markup as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

or comment it out

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="left"></div><!--
 --><div class="right">
</div>
```

or reduce their `width` to something less than `100%` in order to accommodate the whitespace after `inline-block` elements.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Rg6J/) (*click the remove button*)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="contener">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

And now some easy jQuery:

```
$(".right").click(function() {

        $(this).hide();

    $(".left").css({ 'text-align': 'center'});
});
```

So with that we make "desapear" the right one, and then you do what you want with the left one! :)

Comment: I didn't know how you wanted it to be "gone", so I just hide it. And I didn't get if you wanted the text or the div to be centered. But with that you can do what you want in jQuery and then modify the css.